# Qt Interface: undefined interface error

Tags: qt, qt4, kdevelop, moc

I'm trying to write a plugin for KDevelop and I'm having an interface problem. Whenever I include QInterfaces(KDevelop::"Interface" I get an undefined interface error when doing the MOC step. Any ideas what going on? This also happens if I compile one of the kdevelop plugins as a single entity that was packaged with the kdevelop source code. I must be missing some linker option or library or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy-and-paste here the specific error you receive?

Comment: After 2 days of work, I think I have figured out the problem. I wasn't including the right include headers from KDevelop. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Occurred to me that I've got "Error: Undefined interface" from moc regarding file that was targeted towards multiple Qt versions.

```
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 5, 0))
#include <QtUiPlugin/QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>
#else
#include <QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface>
#endif
```

The outcome was that C++ precompiler manages to evaluate QT_VERSION_CHECK macro, but moc does NOT.
You need to re-phrase condition as direct version number

```
#if (QT_VERSION >= 0x050500)
```

this way C++ and moc can do the job and includes the file

Answer (score 0):

Using Intellisense in VS 2010 when installing QVTK I get to the source of the error undefined interface: There is a reference to an include file which does not have the correct path set. Check all libraries includes that the path set is correct.

Answer (score 0):

i get `error: Undefined interface` from MOC when an include file is missing

```cc
// folder/subfolder/somewidget.h

#include "subfolder/someinterface.h" // (not found)

class SomeWidget : public ISomeInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_INTERFACES(ISomeInterface) // error: Undefined interface
```

fixed by adding

```
# CMakeLists.txt

include_directories(folder)
```