# Mysterious Qt undefined interface : investigation

Tags: qt, interface, compiler-errors

I am writing a typical Qt (4.8.2) app with plugins. One of the plugins includes a couple custom interfaces, by calling the Q_INTERFACE macro. Those interfaces are found in .h files visible to the project (via the .pro includes) and they all contain a macro call to Q_DECLARE_INTERFACES.

Yet upon compiling the **moc file** I get an **undefined interface error** in the main .h file of the plugin. It doesn't tell me which though, it only specifies the line of the first (I tried changing the order but it makes no difference - unless *all* interfaces are affected - heck, who knows, that could be the case.)

This plugin works at other people's desks. Some of the stuff in the main app is written with Qt 5 but always with macros to check for the version and include other code for earlier versions like mine. This also works at other people's desks who work with 4.8.2 for their plugins.

Where to look for the cause of that error ?

Comment: Why did I get a negative vote ?

Comment: see also [Qt Interface: undefined interface error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107428/qt-interface-undefined-interface-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why my question got voted down, but here's the answer :

With the copy of the project I also received the moc_*.cpp files and some files called **mocinclude.tmp** . This was a  first *git add* mistake.

But there is another problem : at least the latter (if not the former) does not get cleaned properly or recreated by Qmake/make clean.

A third problem : In *mocinclude.tmp* there were **absolute** file paths from the computer where the project was first created, which wasn't mine. Relative paths would have been less error-prone.

Those wrong absolute paths led to the "undefined interface" error (which is nothing less but a "file not found" error in the case of a needed interface file) when compiling the moc files.

Deleting all *mocinclude.tmp* (and moc files) solved my problem.

(I also made sure to tell git to not track them anymore.)